# Small Basic & syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, smallbasic

I'm playing around with [Small Basic](https://smallbasic-publicwebsite.azurewebsites.net/). I love the built-in IDE, but I'd also like to use Visual Studio Code with it from time-to-time. However, I don't see a extension in the Marketplace that provides any sort of syntax highlighting, auto-completion, etc. Does such a thing exist anywhere? If not, how hard would it be to create one?

Comment: @Martheen : I don’t know, but I’ll check it out!

Comment: @Martheen : While I'm checking out the option to create a custom language, can this question please remain open? As far as I can tell, it is NOT a duplicate. I wasn't asking how to *create* a language in VS. I want to know if one *already exists* somewhere for Small Basic.

Comment: If you're asking "if one already exists", then it's asking for an extension recommendation, which is off-topic.

Comment: No, I’m not asking for a recommendation.

Comment: "if one already exists somewhere" is literally asking for a recommendation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I disagree. See item number 4. My question could be answered yes or no. There’s no opinion involved. I’m not asking which extension(s), nor asking anyone to tell me where to find them.